# BootStrap form Helper Country Picker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap form helper to make a form in php. Everything is working fine But I am unable to get the country name in the php form field. The country field is styled with the bootstrapformhelper and it is wrapped in div instead to input tag.

Here is the code.

```
if(isset($_POST['country'])){
    $country= $_POST['country'];
    echo $country;
}
?>

<form action="rough.php" method="post">

    <div id="country"class="col-sm-8 bfh-selectbox bfh-countries" data-country="NG" data-flags="true">  
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

How can I get the value to php?

Answer (score 3):

```
<div id="country"class="col-sm-8 bfh-selectbox bfh-countries" data-country="NG" data-name="country" data-flags="true">  
</div>
```

You need to have a name first.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$country= $_POST['country']; 
//INSERT QUERY HERE
}
```

Now you have the value. Note that this will not give you the complete name of the country. For example, you chose United States, it will give you US.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but what if I need to get full value of country? For example, I chose "United States", and I want value to submit exactly like "United State", not just "US"?

Answer (score 0):

Try This for Country

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
<select class="input-medium form-control bfh-countries" data-country="US"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider explaining why your answer solves the question.