# Retrieve Bootstrap country picker selected value

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, post

I use Bootstrap form helper country picker to list countries, and I want to retrieve the selected value to insert it in a db table. How can I retrieve the selected value?

```
<div id="country" class="bfh-selectbox bfh-countries" data-country="US" data-flags="true">
</div>
```

I tried to send it using jQuery, but nothing retrieved, I don't know where the selected option is saved!

```
 $("#reg_form").on("submit", function () {
        var hvalue = $('#country').attr('data-country');
        $(this).append("<input type='hidden' name='country' value=' " + hvalue + " '/>");
    });
```

Link for the country picker example 4:
http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/country/#jquery-plugins

Comment: You can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322225/bootstrap-form-helper-country-picker